# How to get IP form browser address bar using PHP?

Tags: php, url, ip

I want to get IP form browser address bar using PHP.

Ip is

```
https://192.168.40.32/example.com/
```

I want only IP like `192.168.40.32`.

I am using this function to get IP :

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

But i shown double IP continue like this:

```
192.168.40.32192.168.40.32
```

So how can i get IP ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You should take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) also

Another way to grab the ip is by using `explode`

```
$url='https://192.168.40.32/example.com/';
$first=explode('//',$url);
$string=explode('/',$first[1]);
var_dump($string[0]); //192.168.40.32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
<?php 
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ipAddress = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}

?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that tries to find an ip address in the url bar, if it doesnt fint any ip there it will look for an ip address in the $_SERVER array.

```
<?php
function uriIP() {
    $s = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    //Look for a number with dots made like: ***.*.**.*** ex.
    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}/i', $s, $matches);
    if (!isset($matches[0])) {

        //Check to see if we have an IP address stored in the $_SERVER array
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) {
            //Return the value if we find any (true)
            return $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        } else {
            //nothing found here, return false
            return false;
        }
    //if we found a match in our regex, return the first match:
    } else {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}
print_r(uriIP());
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ip address is repeats in the string, better to use regex.
[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
//Example - 1
$server_name='https://192.168.40.32/example.com/192.168.40.33/192.168.40.34'; //$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$pattern = '/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/'; //regex pattern
preg_match($pattern, $server_name, $ip_data); //get the correct ip address
$ip = $ip_data[0]; //its an array 
print_r($ip); // display to see result.
?>
```

Check the result: https://eval.in/534366

You can get the ip address with use;

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

```
<?php
//Example - 2
$url = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get the ip address
$my_valid_ip = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP); // check the ip address if its valid
print_r($my_valid_ip); //display to see result.
?>
```